# Aggregate overtimestamps in pandas e calculate mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe structured as well:

```
Timestamp                      Value
2021-06-07T03:19:49.000+0000   8
2021-06-07T03:20:19.000+0000   4
2021-06-07T03:20:49.000+0000   3
2021-06-08T03:11:05.000+0000   2
2021-06-08T03:11:35.000+0000   6
```

The result I want is this, where I aggregate per day and compute the mean:

```
Timestamp    Value
2021-06-07   5
2021-06-08   4
```

How can I do it using pandas? Do I need to cast the timastamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Series.Groupby`

```
out = df.groupby(df.Timestamp.dt.date)['Value'].mean().reset_index()
out
Out[82]: 
    Timestamp  Value
0  2021-06-07    5.0
1  2021-06-08    4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the index is a pd.DatetimeIndex, then you can do this:

```py
df = df.resample('D').mean()
```